# Rails 3, twitter bootstrap functionality is not loading

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, less, precompile

I am using ubuntu 10.10. In my rails 3.1 project, css & javascript code is not loading even after precompile. I am using twitter bootstrap tool but this functionality is not working. Eg: Icons are not loading, buttons UI is not displaying properly.

I am using below command to precompile,

```
rake assets:precompile -t
```

In application.rb i have given

```
config.assets.enabled = true
config.encoding = "utf-8"
```

My development.rb is like,

```
Azzist::Application.configure do

 config.cache_classes = false
 config.whiny_nils = true
 config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
 config.action_controller.perform_caching = true
 config.log_level = :debug

 config.assets.precompile += %w( abootstrap.js bootstrap-timepicker.js jquery.imgareaselect.pack.js application.css cv_builder.css widget.css imgareaselect-default.css)

 config.assets.compile = true
 config.serve_static_assets = true
 config.assets.compress = true
 config.assets.js_compressor  = :uglifier

 config.action_dispatch.best_standards_support = :builtin

 config.autoload_paths += %W(#{Rails.root}/app/sweepers)
 config.action_controller.page_cache_directory = "#{Rails.root}/cache/pages"
 config.cache_store = :dalli_store

 config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
 config.i18n.fallbacks = true
 config.active_support.deprecation = :notify

 # Default url options
 ENV["HOST"] = "http://localhost:3000"
 ENV["LOG_IT"] = "true"
 config.action_mailer.default_url_options = {:host => ENV["HOST"]}
 default_url_options[:host] = ENV["HOST"]

 config.action_controller.asset_host = "http://localhost:3000"

 ## Setting up the memcache server
 ENV["MEMCACHE_SERVER"] = "http://localhost:3000"

end
```

My application.js is,

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs

//= require twitter/bootstrap
//= require bootstrap-button
//= require bootstrap-datepicker
//= require jquery.tokeninput
//= require jquery.vticker
//= require jquery.Jcrop.min
//= require jquery.effects.core
//= require jquery.effects.highlight
//= require highlight
//= require noty

//= require tinymce-jquery

//= require jquery.joyride-1.0.3
//= require jquery.bxslider
//= require jquery.bxslider.min

//= require jquery.jcarousel.min
//= require modernizr-2.5.3.min

//= require_tree .
```

My application.css is,

```
/*

* require_self
* require_tree . 

*= require main
*= require bootstrap_override
*= require datepicker
*= require typography
*= require token-input
*= require token-input-facebook

*= require skin
*= require jquery.ptTimeSelect
*= require jquery.Jcrop
*= require jquery.bxslider

*= require joyride-1.0.3

*= require noty
*= require noty_theme_twitter

*= require_self

*/
```

Need some assistance. Long before i was asked this same question but still it is not solved.

Comment: The problems in those cases are in loading js and css . Post your `application.css` and `application.js`. How do you include the bootstrap - copy/paste or as a gem ?

Comment: We are using bootstrap gem

Answer (score 1):

```
# Do not compress assets
config.assets.compress = false
config.assets.precompile = false
```

Try using app without precompile and compress.

Answer (score 0):

I can see in you `application.css` you have a doubled statement `require_self` . Normally you should place all the required files before `require_tree` and `require_self`.

The other nice practice is : in development do not precompile assets , they should be used as source , because they should reflect the changes you make during dev process .

- require_self and * require_tree . won't do anything as its a comment. "=" (equal sign) is required inorder to consider it as a include statement.

Comment: * require_self and * require_tree . won't do anything as its a comment. "=" (equal sign) is required inorder to consider it as a include statement.

Comment: Exactly , you are absolutely right ! Add it to your answer , sir.

Comment: Thank you , sir . I hope it will help.